# How deep should my entryway be?

Tags: walls, doors

[image]

The side entrance to my house is just off the driveway and most people enter the house from there. This is the entrance to my wife's office which is a now enclosed slab porch. If the door is open, or the blinds up, you can see from the street, through the office, into the dining room and, finally, me in my underwear in the kitchen. I don't like that.

I'm remodeling that office and was thinking of putting a wall up in front of the door to block that view. This way, when one enters from outside, I can have coat hooks just inside the door for visitors and, to the left, would be a bench for taking snow boots off or whatever.

My concern is how far away from the door should this wall be? I don't want people coming in and feel the wall in their face or crowded while taking their coat off. Of course, it has to be deep enough for the door to open fully but is there a rule-of-thumb for this?

I don't want it too deep because we're converting it into a family room so there will be furniture on the other side of this wall.

Comment: Rob, I think it would enhance your question a great deal if you could add a sketch of the layout that you are working with. Even better if it was approximately to scale.

Comment: It depends a bit on the size of the space. The entryway acts like a hallway, so hallway width guidelines could work for you, but you don't need an entryway that is excessively large compared to the room. Why not put up a temporary partition and adjust it until you find a good location. Then put a wall there?

Comment: prop up a temporary wall .... use a sheet of plywood or a large piece of furniture or even drapes of some kind ..... it should give you a feel for the new entry way